# Function 'is not a function' in Javascript class - but only on mobile

Tags: javascript, class, mobile

I have created a class which works well on desktop. But when run on mobile I am getting error `this.getDragPointer is not a function`. So why is it a function when on desktop, but not on mobile?
I have researched other questions concerning 'function is not a function' but haven't found anything similar.

```
export class Draggable {
  // other vars and functions....

    onMouseDown(e) {
        this.getDragPointer(e.clientX, e.clientY)
        this.prepareElement()
        this.moveElementTo(e.pageX, e.pageY)
        document.addEventListener('mousemove', this.onMouseMove);
    }
    onTouchStart(e) {
        this.isTouch = true;
        this.getDragPointer(e.touches[0].clientX, e.touches[0].clientY)   // fails here
        this.prepareElement()
        this.moveElementTo(e.touches[0].pageX, e.touches[0].pageY)
        document.addEventListener('touchmove', this.onMouseMove);
    }
    getDragPointer = function(x, y) {
        const elRect = this.el.getBoundingClientRect()
        this.shiftX = x - elRect.left
        this.shiftY = y - elRect.top
    }
}
```

`onMouseDown`, caling the same function, works as it should. `onTouchStart` fails.
Debugging on android using Chrome remote tools, if it's relevant.

Comment: Is there a special reason why you assign to a field like `getDragPointer = ...` instead of using a method like `getDragPointer(x, y) {` ?

Comment: No reason, tried both to solve problem! Both work on desktop, both fail on mobile.

Comment: Do you have `document.addEventListener('touchstart', this.onTouchStart)` somewhere? If not bound, then `this.getDragPointer` may become undefined, and the JS engine will tell you that it "is not a function". Try using `bind` [MDN reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind)

Comment: Yes! In the constructor, but I hadn't bound it like you just suggested. I now have `this.onTouchStart = this.onTouchStart.bind(this)` as well as ` this.onMouseDown = this.onMouseDown.bind(this)`. Thank you! now working,